# My Image aren't correctly display in my JPanel

Tags: java, image

after i tried many things on my little application, i still have a problem with my image.
I create an application who can display the image of a folder but they are flatted when to many of them or cutt off. So i tried to use a JScrollPane to resolve the issue and just have to scrool to get the other images, but it still don't work. If some of you can provide me a little help, thank you.
here is my code

```
 private void placeComponents() {
  imageFrame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);

  Border border = BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder();
  JPanel sidePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1)); {
   JPanel categoriePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER)); {
    JPanel categorie = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1)); {
     categoriePanel.add(randomButton);
     categoriePanel.setBorder(border);
    }
    categoriePanel.add(categorie);
   }
   sidePanel.add(categoriePanel);
  }
  JPanel displayPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1)); {
   JPanel imgPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(imgList.getImageList().length / 3, 3, 2, 2)); {

    for (BufferedImage i: imgList.getImageList()) {
     JPanel currentImg = new JPanel() {
      @Override
      protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);

       int width = i.getWidth() * (displayPanel.getWidth() / 2) / i.getWidth();
       int height = i.getHeight() * (displayPanel.getWidth() / 2) / i.getWidth();
       g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, width, height, null);
      }

     };

     imgPanel.add(currentImg);
    }
   }
   scrollPane = new JScrollPane(imgPanel);
   scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
   scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

   displayPanel.add(scrollPane);

  }

  imageFrame.add(sidePanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
  imageFrame.add(displayPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

 }
```

i create a random button on the side and in an other panel i tried to display the image stock in my BufferedImage array.
this is the actual result :

[image: resultWhenItsNotWorkingCorrectly]

we can see that image are flatted or cut

Comment: I use this calculation to have a scaled shape of my image in the label from what they original mesure. And i thought that  ```drawImage```  will size the image with the arg width and height . If you got any idea how to refactor that ?

Comment: currently i see the things like this, i want an image A with a width of Y to fit in a panel of width Y' , in order to do so, i multiplie Y with the ratio Y/Y' to fit Y in Y', but i use the same on the length because i don't want my picture to get difformed, so i use the same ratio.

Comment: yeah you right, i don't know how i could even get to this calculation. the dislayPanel is used as a container for all the pictures, i want to have if possible 2 pictures by row, (even if something dynamic depending on the size of the frame should be better). With your advise i finally managed to get somethin good when their is few images. I still got an issues when their is too many, they all flatted  and my scrollBar dosen't allow me to scroll

Comment: i tried to do something that adapted the number of pictures by row depending of the list of pictures, because i want to display all the images of my folder but only 3 (not 2 as i say before) per row, and so i need 3 column and (nbr of picture / 3) row.

Comment: you can leave one of `columns`  or `rows`  as zero, it will be calculated by the layout manager

Comment: by doing that i indeed got all my image in my JPanel and none of them are "flatted" but their all appears small,  i am getting closer to the result i want. Now i just need to find out how use the scrollBar to get normale sized picture in a JPannel and just have to scroll to see the other pictures if their is too much of them

Comment: i try different layout but i ending with different problems, i change the preferredSize of my currentImage and even if it's not perfect cause i need to redo the calculation thing, i finally get something who work, thank you very much for all your help and you time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the size of the component the image is being drawn into:

```java
//  ...
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        // use the same minimum rate to avoid distortion
        // and still have the whole image painted
        double ratio = Math.min( (double)getHeight()/i.getHeight(), 
                                 (double)getWidth()/i.getWidth()  );
        int width = (int) (i.getWidth() * ratio);
        int height = (int) (i.getHeight() * ratio);

        g.drawImage(i, 0, 0, width, height, null);
    }
//  ...
```

This should also work if the frame size is changed.

Comment: i try your solution, and the result his a little bit better if i use Math.max, even if i still have the issues of flatted images when i got too many pictures, thank you for you solution.

Comment: yes, but i got a probleme with picture who have a bigger width than heigth so i just need to  compare the width and the heigth of the picture first.